# how to achieve the follwing layout in Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image: Layout]

Can anyone help me to achieve this layout using Bootstrap classess please ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried but the alignment is not coming properly

Comment: @Siva Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with built-in classes without writing an additional css

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center border border-primary rounded">
  <div class="h1 m-0 text-primary py-2 px-3">
    $16,0000
  </div>
  <div class="bg-primary text-white text-center py-2 px-3">
    <div class="h2 m-0">
      63
     </div>
    <div class="small">
      Days
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here you go...**

You just need to change the CSS to get the desired result (change colors, fonts, widths, heights, etc.), but the structure is set. You can also change Bootstrap class prefixes if you want (currently set to `col-sm-`).

```css
.row {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 18vh;
}

#price {
  color: #000099;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#days {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
  background-color: #000099;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-9 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center' id='price'>$16,000</div>
      <div class='col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-center' id='days'>63<br> Days</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with

```
<Container className='border' style={{width:'300px'}}>
    <Row className='align-items-center'>
      <Col>
        <h1>$16,000</h1>
      </Col>
      <Col xs md='3' className='border text-light text-center' style={{background:'darkblue', padding:'5px'}}>
        <h1>63</h1>
        <span>Days</span>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
```

I advise using tailwindcss instead. Bootstrap isn't that broad.